# returning different datatypes from a function in python

Tags: python, function, sparse-matrix

How do we return a sparse matrix and an array data from a function. My sparse matrix is

**sparse_mat**

<540x5550 sparse matrix of type ''
    with 9068 stored elements in COOrdinate format>

and the other data is **session_id**:

```
array([['192.168.113.111_timesofindia.indiatimes.com_1', 'User'],
     ['192.168.113.111_timesofindia.indiatimes.com_2', 'User'],
      dtype='|S46')
```

I want to return both these data from a function.Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can return more than one value from a Python function by returning a tuple:

```
return sparse_mat, session_id
```

The caller can get the returned value by something like:

```
m, id = your_function()
```

Oh, and it doesn't make any difference if there are two different data types. You can return two values of the same type too of course.

Answer (score 3):

Use a tuple:

```
 def foo(x, y):
   sum = x + y
   return (x, y, sum)
```

See? I returned 3 items. And what is more, if I know the airity of the tuple, then I can use an extractor to capture them:

```
 (m, n, total) = foo(4, 5)
```

wherein `m` is assigned `4`, `n` is assigned `5` and `total` is assigned `9`.

Answer (score 2):

Examples

```
def return2():
    a = {1:1}
    b = 'b'
    return a,b

def anotherReturn2():
    a = {1:1}
    b = 'b'
    return {'a' : a, 'b' : b}

a_1, b_1 = return2()
a_2 = return2()[0]
b_2 = return2()[1]
print a_1, b_1, a_2, b_2

a_1, b_1 = anotherReturn2()
a_2 = anotherReturn2()['a']
b_2 = anotherReturn2()['b']
print a_1, b_1, a_2, b_2

>>> 
{1: 1} b {1: 1} b
a b {1: 1} b
>>>
```